# Django forms custom validation on two fields one or the other

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm struggling with the following and need some guidance, below you will see my form.py. I have two fields called `group` and `single`. I need to apply the following rules/validation to them...

- A user must either enter a single number or select at least one group but never both

So a user can never select both a group and a enter a single number at the same time, but they must have one or the other. Hope that makes sense?

Because of these rules I cannot just add `required = true` and need some sort of custom validation. It's this custom validation I''m having problems with.

Could anyone give me an example based on my form of the sort of validation I would need?

Thanks.

Forms.py

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BatchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            form_choices = Group.objects.for_user(user).annotate(c=Count('contacts')).filter(c__gt=0)
        else:
            form_choices = Group.objects.all()
        self.fields['group'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=form_choices, required=False
        )
        self.fields['single'] = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to handle that in the form's `clean` method.
Something like this:

```
class BatchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    ...
    def clean(self):
        check = [self.cleaned_data['single'], self.cleaned_data['group']]
        if any(check) and not all(check):
            # possible add some errors
            return self.cleaned_data
        raise ValidationError('Select any one')
```

Comment: is there a syntax error in your code? indents maybe? I don't see how I can rise error after you return something.

Comment: try it out it would work. I am returning in the `if` clause or else raise validation error.

Comment: also I think your missing a ] at the end right? not sure, i'll try it thanks

Comment: Try it out buddy. If something is broken, you can always fix it.

Comment: ok, so let me understand this... 'any' is a new keyword to me. So any looks at both fields in the check var and if one is ok else if both rise! that's cool stuff! How come tho on the form error the says... _all__ Select any one - where has 'all' come from?

Comment: all checks if all of them evaluate to `True`

Comment: Later, Won't a form.is_valid() check fail, since one of the keys will be missing, either single or group ?

Comment: it wont, if you set `required` to False @yeaske

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) explains exactly how to validate forms that depend on each other, via the form's `clean()` method.

Comment: As I and the documentation state, clean is correct. You should not override is_valid.